# Mysql query execution time reduse

Tags: php, mysql

i have three tables in one database like this:
company,categories,seo.
i use this query :

```
SELECT seo.seo, company.diafhmish, comp_cat.cat, company.category, company.foto, comp_cat.diaf, company.comp_id, company.comp_name, company.perifereia, company.polh, company.thl, company.adress 
FROM company 
INNER JOIN comp_cat 
ON comp_cat.comp=company.comp_id 
INNER JOIN categories 
ON comp_cat.cat=categories.cat_id 
LEFT JOIN seo 
ON seo.comp=company.comp_id
WHERE categories.category = '$kathgoria' AND 
company.perifereia = '$polh' 
ORDER BY company.comp_name ASC
```

this take about 2,5 sec to execute, but if i try the same query without LEFT JOIN piece the time reduse at 0,5 sec!!
Is there any way to replase the LEFT JOIN piece?

```
EXPLAIN:

id | select_type | table | type possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | Extra

1 | SIMPLE | comp_cat | ALL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 15549 | Using temporary; Using filesort

1 | SIMPLE | company | eq_ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 4 | tileodig_tileodigos.comp_cat.comp | 1 | Using where

1 | SIMPLE | seo | ALL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 1283

1 | SIMPLE | categories | eq_ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 4 | tileodig_tileodigos.comp_cat.cat | 1 | Using where
```

I change the line `LEFT JOIN seo ON seo.comp=company.comp_id` 
with: `LEFT JOIN seo ON seo.comp=comp_cat.comp`
both columns have the same value and i solved the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How would I make this query run faster?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6532591/how-would-i-make-this-query-run-faster)

Comment: In general with performance related questions, it depends.  You should benefit though from having the correct indices on your tables.  What do you currently have?

Comment: please show us the output from **EXPLAIN SELECT seo.seo, company.diafhmish, comp_cat.cat, company.category, company.foto, comp_cat.diaf, company.comp_id, company.comp_name, company.perifereia, company.polh, company.thl, company.adress FROM company INNER JOIN comp_cat ON comp_cat.comp=company.comp_id INNER JOIN categories ON comp_cat.cat=categories.cat_id LEFT JOIN seo ON seo.comp=company.comp_id** it look like that there is a index missing

Comment: and the schema is needed. `show create table xyz` for each table `xyz`

Comment: If you solved the problem, you should add the solution below.